# How can I make the arrow red and keep the line blue?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a blue line with a red arrow in the middle, but everything just showed as blue. The following is my code, I don't know how to fix it. Please help me. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(-3,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,2){B}
    \draw[Blue, thick, postaction={decorate, red, decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}}] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(-3,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(-2,2){B}
        \draw[blue, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[red]{stealth}}}}] (A)--(B);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: red arrow on a blue line]

Comment: Seems like you don't have to load neither the `decorations.markings` nor the `arrows` libraries when `tkz-euclide`is already on.